# Lumen API select data with group by aggreated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, lumen

I'm currently using Lumen 5.7 for my back end API .I need to select some fields from multiple tables with using left join.
I have the following query(Plain mysql query)

```
SELECT issue_id,issue_receipt_id, date_format(issue_datetime, '%d-%m-%Y') as issue_datetime,
issue_item,sum(issue_wt) as issue_wt, round(avg(issue_pure),3) as issue_pure,
sum(issue_fine) as issue_fine, sum(issue_cash) as issue_cash,
sum(receipt_wt) as receipt_wt, sum(receipt_fine) as receipt_fine,
pure_name as issue_item_name 
FROM item_issues 
LEFT JOIN receipt_items ON receipt_id = issue_receipt_id 
LEFT JOIN purities ON pure_id = issue_item
group by issue_receipt_id;
```

And I have tried in lumen as like,

```
$receipts = DB::table('item_issues')            
            ->leftJoin('receipt_items', 'receipt_items.receipt_id', '=', 'item_issues.issue_receipt_id')
            ->leftJoin('purities', 'purities.pure_id', '=', 'item_issues.issue_item')
            ->select('issue_id', 'issue_receipt_id', DB::raw("date_format(issue_datetime, '%d-%m-%Y') as issue_datetime"), 'issue_item', 'pure_name', DB::raw('sum(issue_wt) as issue_wt'), 
            DB::raw('round(avg(issue_pure),3) as issue_pure'),
            DB::raw('sum(issue_fine) as issue_fine'),
            DB::raw('sum(issue_cash) as issue_cash'),
            DB::raw('sum(receipt_wt) as receipt_wt'),
            DB::raw('sum(receipt_fine) as receipt_fine'))
            ->groupBy('item_issues.issue_receipt_id', 'item_issues.issue_item')->get();
```

But it producing error like Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'item_issues.issue_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
But I have to select the above fields, how to do this without the issue. And I have tried to disable strict mode but I don't know where to disable this option whether in .env or in some other file. I couldn't find the database.config in lumen. Any one can help on this.

Comment: You are probably writing a query that makes no sense. BTW: The plain query would also raise an error in strict mode.

Comment: No while I check in mysql workbench it is giving a result

Comment: Because the server isn't strict by default. Lumen sets the strict mode for a single session. Try `set session sql_mode = concat('only_full_group_by,', @@sql_mode);` in Workbench, and then execute your query.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is not any folder named `'config/database.php'` in Lumen application. but feel free to add this config file to your lumen applicaion like in laravel.

and paste the below peace of code in your database.php file.

```
return [
    'default' => 'mysql',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'strict'    => false
        ]
    ]
]
```

the important thing here is `'strict' => false` mode.